# Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Tabs from Material UI where I'm displaying a List component filtered by the tab, please see the code of the Tabs in my Container Component:

```
              <Tabs
                    className="DrawerTabs"
                    inkBarStyle={{ display: 'none' }}
                >
                    <Tab label="Headline"
                         data-route="/headline"
                         onActive={this.handleActive}
                         className={this.isActive('Headline')}
                    >
                        <div>
                            <ModulesListContainer
                                filter="Headline"
                            />

                        </div>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab label="Body"
                         data-route="/body"
                         onActive={this.handleActive}
                         className={this.isActive('Body')}
                    >
                        <div>
                            <ModulesListContainer
                                filter="Body"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab
                        label="Other"
                        data-route="/other"
                        onActive={this.handleActive}
                        className={this.isActive('Other')}
                    >
                        <div>
                            <ModulesListContainer
                                filter="Other"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
```

and the code of the ModuleList I placed in each of the tabs which is showing only items based on the filter passed from the Container Component:

```
        const ModulesList = (props) => {

            let ListItems = props.modulesProps.map(module => {

                if (props.filter === module.category) {
                    return (
                        <ListItem
                            key={module.id}
                            className="ModulePreview"
                        >
                            {module.id} - {module.name} - {module.thumbnail}
                            <FontAwesome
                                name="plus-circle"
                                size="2x"
                                onClick={props.addModule.bind(this, module)}
                                className="AddModule"
                            />
                        </ListItem>
                    )
                }
            })

            return (
                <div className="ModulesList">
                    <List>
                        {ListItems}
                    </List>
                </div>
            )
        }
```

Even though I can see only the filtered items in each of the tabs (thus key is unique as each item is there only once) I'm still getting this warning:

> Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same
>   key, `1`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key,
>   only the first child will be used.

Why is that?

Any help / ideas / tips would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meaning of that line is `module.id` is not unique, there will be 2 `objects` in `array` that have the same `id=1`, to avoid that you can use index of `object`, it will always be unique.

Use this:

```
let ListItemsUI = [];
props.modulesProps.forEach((module, i) => {
    if (props.filter === module.category) {
        ListItemsUI.push (
            <ListItem
                key={i}
                className="ModulePreview"
            >
                {module.id} - {module.name} - {module.thumbnail}
                <FontAwesome
                    name="plus-circle"
                    size="2x"
                    onClick={props.addModule.bind(this, module)}
                    className="AddModule"
                />
            </ListItem>
        )
    }
})

return (
     <div className="ModulesList">
          <List>
              {ListItemsUI}
          </List>
     </div>
)
```

One more thing `map` is not suitable for these cases where you want to `return` only few element on the basis of condition, use `forEach` for that. Reason is if you don't `return` anything, by default `map` will return `undefined`.

Check the output of this example:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

let b = a.map(el=>{
    if(el % 2 == 0)
       return el;
})

console.log(b);
```

Comment: thanks for that, i'm not getting the warning anymore however every item appears 3x times because i have the element on the page three times (in each of the tabs), guess i need to prevent duplication if the element is in the array already it shouldn't be pushed again...which I could do using the id - it is unique for each module

Comment: you have to remove the duplicate entries from array, i think. how you are prepapring that array ?

Comment: it's just an empty array ListItems = [] then i added data-itemid={module.id} in <ListItem> so I can determine duplicates

Comment: why would something like this not work?

    const ListItemsUnique = []
    ListItems.map(item => {
        if (ListItemsUnique.indexOf(item.props['data-itemid']) === -1) {
            ListItemsUnique.push(item)
        }
    })

Comment: i think issue is item will be an object, and you are pushing that object in unique list, and checking the index of `data-itemid`.

Comment: it's been answered already - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254382/remove-array-items-where-object-property-is-not-unique