# Remove array items where object property is not unique

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array with objects and I need to remove duplicates based on the `data-itemid` prop.

This is my code:

```
const ListItemsUnique = []
ListItems.map(item => {
  if (ListItemsUnique.indexOf(item.props['data-itemid']) === -1) {
    ListItemsUnique.push(item)
  }
});
```

It returns exactly the same array as before, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: show the actual `ListItemsUnique` contents

Comment: it contains exactly the same objects as the ListItems array, if I push item.props['data-itemid'] into the ListItemsUnique it works correctly but obviously only the id's are in the array, I need the objects to be there

Comment: Have you tried `filter` instead, and then returning an object when found!

Comment: @funcoding how would the code look like, please?

Comment: Can you show a sample of `ListItems` contents?

Comment: I think the following post could help you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and cleanest way would be to use a temporary set to store which items you have previously returned to your array, while you're mapping through it. Like so:

```
let tempSet = new Set();
const ListItemsUnique = ListItems.filter(item => {
  if(!tempSet.has(item.props['data-itemid'])) {
      tempSet.add(item.props['data-itemid']);
    return item;
  }
});
```

then do your mapping as usual.

---

#### Demo

```js
let ListItems = [
  {name: "A", props: {"data-itemid": 1}},
  {name: "B", props: {"data-itemid": 1}},
  {name: "C", props: {"data-itemid": 2}},
  {name: "D", props: {"data-itemid": 3}},
  {name: "E", props: {"data-itemid": 3}},
];  //mock data

let tempSet = new Set();
const ListItemsUnique = ListItems.filter(item => {
  if(!tempSet.has(item.props['data-itemid'])) {
    tempSet.add(item.props['data-itemid']);
    return item;
  }
})

console.log(ListItemsUnique.map(item => item.name));  //Items "B" and "E" are skipped
```

---

By the way, `Set` is great for when dealing with, or wanting to achieve, a unique collection of data. Have a read on the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for more info on `Set`.

Here's a snippet from the docs:

> `Set` objects are collections of values. You can iterate through the elements of a set in insertion order. A value in the `Set` may only occur once; it is unique in the `Set`'s collection.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using ES6, Try this,

```
const ListItemsUnique = [...new Set(ListItems.map(item => item.props['data-itemid']))];
```

EDIT 1:

```
let data = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    "data-itemid": 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Doe',
    "data-itemid": 1
  },
  {
    name: 'James',
    "data-itemid": 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Clerk',
    "data-itemid": 2
  }
];

// Use Map (ES6) to retain only unique elements
let map = new Map();
for (element of data) {
  map.set(element["data-itemid"], element);
}


var filteredData = [];
map.forEach( (value) => {
  filteredData.push(value);
});

console.log(filteredData,"filteredData");
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/vedp/pen/RpmVvx?editors=0011

Comment: it returns an array with those IDs only whether I need objects instead

Comment: This only returns the unique `data-itemid` values, not the whole item. Also, you are mapping the wrong array. :)

Comment: @Ved, nice. Have an upvote. But you should probably ping the OP also ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use immutable js or JSON.stringify (depending on how deep ur objects are or how deep you want to compare ;) )

1. use [immutablejs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) - fromJS + compare
2. use JSON.stringify

Example for JSON.stringify

```js
const ListItems = [{a: 'a'}, {a: 'b'}, {a: 'a'}];

let ListItemsUnique = [];
let stringList = [];

ListItems.forEach(item => {
    const itemString = JSON.stringify(item);
    if (stringList.indexOf(itemString) === -1) {
        ListItemsUnique.push(item);
    }
    stringList.push(itemString);
})

console.log(ListItemsUnique);
```